# Performance Tuning--Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, indexing

Is there any scope of tuning below  query and increase the performance

```
SELECT
    i.store_id,
    i.film_id,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(*) - (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM rental 
        WHERE
            inventory_id IN (SELECT inventory_id FROM inventory
                             WHERE inventory.film_id = i.film_id AND
                                   inventory.store_id = i.store_id)
    ) 
FROM `inventory` i 
GROUP BY
    i.store_id,
    i.film_id
```

Here I am fetching details on how many are there in store and how may rented  out .

Comment: It might be helpful if you also tell us what this query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: transform the "in" into an inner join

Comment: Its fetching the records .. about how many videos are there in store and how  many rented out

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, subselects perform poorly in MySQL. Temporary tables may be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turn `IN ( SELECT ... )` into a JOIN.

Add `INDEX(store_id, film_id, inventory_id)`